# How does the magnetic field get induced in car's tire?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, everyday-life, magnetic-fields

I was amazed to see how my car's tire started attracting the nuts and bolts, how in the world did it induce the magnetic field? Never heard of such phenomena!!!

Comment: Have you actually tested that it's a magnetic field being induced?  You could check with a compass.  You could also check if iron filing or small metal objects like staples form chains because of a magnetic field inducing a small field in each small metal object.

Comment: What is the car model and year? Which part of the tire are the nuts and bolts sticking to/which part are they attracted to more strongly? Did you make any recent modifications?

Comment: Most car tyres have steel bracing in them.  Perhaps this has become magnetised.

Comment: Many types of steel become magnetized in processing.  It is likely the steel belts in the tire and/or your lug nuts are magnetized.

Answer (score 2):

Car tyres, which these days are almost always [radials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_tire#Construction), are sometimes reinforced with steel. It may be possible that these have become magnetized due to impact in the Earth's field, although I find that unlikely unless you constantly drive in one direction.

Otherwise, maybe someone has run a magnet over your tyres?

Adding quotes from [another paper on the subject](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10495309)

> Magnetic fields emanate from radial tires due to the presence of
>   reinforcing belts which are made of magnetized steel wire. When these
>   tires spin, they generate alternating magnetic fields of extremely low
>   frequency (ELF), usually below 20 Hz. The fundamental frequency of
>   these fields is determined by tire rotation rate and has a sinusoidal
>   waveform with a high harmonic content. The static field of radial
>   tires can exceed 500 microT at the tread, and the tire-generated
>   alternating fields can exceed 2.0 microT at seat level in the
>   passenger compartment of vehicles.

Answer (score 0):

Tyres are made up of rubber. Rubber is an insulating material. During the movement of your car, the tyres get charged due to friction between the tyres and the ground. This causes your tyre to attract other charged materials or even nuetral materials.

Charged rubber attracting nuts and bolts is difficult although it is not impossible. Nuts and bolts are conducting material, thus even if they are charged, charge leaks to the ground. In your case, your tyre should have had more charge which could attract neutral bolts and nuts due electrostatic induction.

Comment: I find it rather hard to believe that static electricity on a car tire caused metal nuts and bolts to stick into it...

Comment: Static electric charges generally arc long, *long* before they attract significant sized objects like "nuts and bolts".

Comment: @dmckee: Agreed, this seems kinda farfetched.

Comment: I tend to think that GODPARTICLE's answer may be reasonable: electrostatic charge on the tire can indeed attract metal objects, as the charge is attracted to its image charge in the metal. You may wish to look at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AC4PAfIEwBs (at about 2:00).